# How to Parse the Text file in SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl

Iam new to SSIS , Iam facing the below issue while parsing a text file which contains the below sample data

Below is the requirement

-> Need to Capture the number after IH1(454756567) and insert into one column as 
   InvoiceNumber
-> Need to insert the data between ABCD1234 to ABCD2345 into another column as 
   TotalRecord .

Many thanks for the help .

ABCD1234

IH1 454756567    686575634

IP2 HJKY TXRT

IBG 23455GHK

ABCD2345

IH1 689343256    686575634

IP2 HJKY TXRT

IBG 23455GHK

ABCD5678

Comment: I would recommend researching a script component, split and switch statement. This will let you process the WHOLE file vs getting the pieces that you need.

Answer (score 2):

This is the script component to process the entire file. You need to create your output and they are currently being processed as strings.

This assumes your file format is consistent. If you don't have 2 columns in IH1 and IP2 ALL the time. I would recommend a for loop from 1 to len -1 to process. And send the records to their own output.

```
public string recordID = String.Empty;
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    string filePath = ""; //put your filepath here
    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line.Substring(0, 4) == "ABCD") //Anything that identifies the start of a new record
                                                // line.Split(' ').Length == 1 also meets your criteria.
            { 
                recordID = line;
                Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                Output0Buffer.RecordID = line;
            }

            string[] cols = line.Split(' ');

            switch (cols[0])
            {
                case "IH1":
                    Output0Buffer.InvoiceNumber = cols[1];
                    Output0Buffer.WhatEverTheSecondColumnIs = cols[2];
                    break;
                case "IP2":
                    Output0Buffer.ThisRow = cols[1];
                    Output0Buffer.ThisRow2 = cols[2];
                    break;
                case "IBG":
                    Output0Buffer.Whatever = cols[1];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do this in a script component.